# Mongoose connecting but cannot connect with database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Mongoose is running the callback after mongoose.connect() as per normal but any further attempts to do anything with the database are not running.

Tried running callbacks/logs as soon on in the process as possible and everything is running normally.

```
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function() {
  console.log("mongodb connected");
});

mongoose.connection.on("connected", function() {
  console.log("connected");
  mongoose.connection.db.collectionNames(function(err, names) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(names);
  });
});
```

I expect it to print out

```
mongodb connected
connected
(list of names)
```

but instead it just prints out
`mongodb connected`

Comment: If your are using mongoose 4 and above. It uses mongodb driver 2.0, which was renamed that function to listCollections(). Try using **mongoose.connection.db.listCollections()**

Comment: The problem isn't the call to that, it doesn't even log connected before that, it just sits there doing nothing.

Comment: Can you check if there is an error in initial connection by listening to error event as well. Or as you have written third callback function takes error as argument: **mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(error){})**. [Mongoose Connection](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)